# Find mutually compatible options from list of list of options

Tags: algorithm, search, computer-science

For purposes of this question, let us call a list of mutually incompatible options for "OptionS". I have a list of such OptionS, where each Option, apart from disqualifying all other Options in it's own OptionS list, also disqualify some Options from the other OptionS lists. These rules are symmetrical, so if A forbids B, B forbids A.

I want to pick exactly one Option from each list, such that no Options disqualify each other. There are too many Options (and OptionS) and too few disqualifications in each step to brute force a backtracking solution.

It reminds be a bit of Sudoku, but it is not an exact analog. From certain external factors, I have a rough likelihood for the different Options, or at least an ordering.

Is there a known better solution to this problem? Is it in NP?

Currently, I plan to just take random "paths" through the solution space, weighted by likelihood. A sort of simulated annealing.

**EDIT - Clarification**

- I have a number, let's say between 5 and 500, of vectors.
- Each vector contains a number, between 10 and 10000, of elements
- Each element rules out a number of elements in the other vectors
- This relation is symmetric
- I want to pick exactly one element from each vector in a way that no elements disqualify each other

If there is no way to choose one from each vector, I want to at least choose as many as possible. The nature of the data is such that there will always be at least one (and at most a few) solution (or almost-solution - with just a few misses).

I cannot share the real data, but an example would be that the elements are integers between 1 and 10e9 and that only elements whose pairwise sum has more than P prime factors are allowed. Some numbers are more likely than others to "fit" other numbers, since larger numbers tend to have more factors, which makes some choices more likely just like the real one.

Pick P and the sizes and number of vectors as needed to make it suitably challenging :).

**My naive solution:**

- I order the elements by how many other elements they rule out and try those who rule out few first (because that gives you a larger chance to be able to pick one from each).
- Then I order the vectors by how many elements the "best" element rules out. Vectors that rule out many other elements are first. So the most constrained vector is tried first, even though the least constrained elements of that vector are tried first.
- I then search depth first

The problem with this approach is that if the first choice is wrong, then the depth first search will never have time to reach the next choice.

A better way, which I try to explain in a comment below, would be to score each partial choice (node in the search tree) of elements according to how many you have chosen and how many elements are left. Then I could look deeper in the highest scoring node at each step, so the first choice is less rigid.

A similar way, which I might try first because it is slightly easier, is to do simulated annealing and take random paths, weighted by how many possibilities they keep, down the tree.

Comment: Reminds me of [SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem)... also, have you tried backtracking with most-constrained-first heuristic?

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, I have tried something similar to most-constrained-first, but if the first choice was wrong, it would never reach the second. I think it could be improved by evaluating number of choices left in a node combined with depth and use that as a fitness measurement in a A* search. That way it could search a bit broader and shallower.

Comment: I am not sure I can follow... maybe you should post (in pseudo-code or actual code) what you've tried and also some test data for trying out stuff.

Comment: @tobias_k Added a clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what constraints are allowed, I think you can reduce SAT to this.

Take a SAT expression e.g. (A|B|C)(~A|C|~D)...
Replace ~A by a and make a vector out of each term giving you {A,B,C} {a,C,d}...

You now have the problem of choosing one element from each vector, subject to the constraint that you cannot choose both versions of a variable - the constraints say that A is incompatible with a, B is incompatible with b, and so on.

If you can solve this instance of your problem you can solve SAT by setting to true variables that are chosen in your problem as A, B, C,... to false variables that are chosen as a, b, c,.. and making an arbitrary choice for anything not chosen - therefore your problem is at least as hard as SAT. (Except if you don't encounter these sorts of constraints, in which case I have not proved that your problem is this hard).

Given an instance of your problem, associate a variable with each element, write the constraints as boolean expressions (typically with only 2 variables) to give something which looks like 2-SAT, except that you need an expression for each vector of the form (A|B|C|D|...) to say that you must choose at least one element from each vector - so the exact solution version of your problem, at least, might code up quite nicely as input for a SAT-solver - so it is in NP and since we have already shown it is NP-hard it is NP-complete.

Comment: This was just what I wanted. It tells me that using information specific to just this problem is probably the correct approach, rather than relying on a general technique.

Answer (score 1):

My first recommendation would be to find an off-the-shelf constraint solver and try that (request a maximum-weight solution with the log-likelihoods as weights), but if you're determined to implement a solver from scratch, then I would suggest that you start with something like [WalkSAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WalkSAT). To summarize the link in the language of your question: at all times, keep a list of option choices (one from each option list, not necessarily compatible) and a list of conflicts (i.e., a set of pairs of indexes into the list of option lists). Repeatedly choose a conflict at random and resolve it by choosing differently for one half of the conflict or the other (most of the time) so as to decrease the number of conflicts afterward as much as possible or (some of the time) randomly, perhaps according to the likelihoods. Good data structures will be essential in making this run fast.

Comment: Thanks. I might look into an off-the-shelf solver. The list of conflicts is too large to keep in memory, though.

Comment: @Gurgeh Not between all values; just the actual conflicts for the current assignment (if the big list has 500 lists, then the number of conflicts is at most 500 choose 2 = 124,750).